# Material-UI React TypeScript Component Styles Error w/ Default Theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm integrating Material-UI (v4.4.3) into a React (v16.9.2) TypeScript (v3.6.3) website. Using the sample AppBar component example https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/ and the TypeScript Guide https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#typescript I have the following functional component.

However, I'm getting a TS error for *useStyles()* on this line

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

*(TS): Expected one argument, but got 0.*

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { createStyles, Theme, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const useStyles = makeStyles(({ spacing }: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
  }),
);

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            MSC
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to use the default theme. Am I missing something?

Comment: What I'm not entirely clear about from the docs and samples is what, if anything, you have to do to make the default theme available to all components.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass an empty object:

```
const classes = useStyles({});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in a "TypeError: spacing is not a function" error.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and passed {} to the useStyles function as I showed in the answer. No error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

try using components from :

```
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar"
import XXX from "@material-ui/core/xxx"
```

XXX = other components

notes my dependencies are:

- dependencies :  `"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.14"`
- devDependencies : `"@types/material-ui": "^0.21.7"`

don't forgot to import `@types/material-ui` devDependencies in your project.